# Nested DataContext

Tags: wpf, binding, datacontext, nested

I have 2 nested `DataContexts` in following code (`DataContext` and `ItemsSource`):

```xml
<TabItem Header="Something" Name="myTabItemName" d:DataContext="{Binding myViewModel}">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding muObservableCollection}" Name="myDataGridName" HeadersVisibility="Column">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Foo 01" Binding="{Binding Foo_01}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Foo 02" Binding="{Binding Foo_02}" />
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="My custom combobox">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <!-- Here I want to bind back to 'myViewModel's' myProperty. I've tried this way: -->
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=myProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</TabItem>
```

I want to assign `myViewModel` (back) to `ComboBox's` `DataContext`. The problem is that `ComboBox` has 'overwritten' `DataContext` in line:

```xml
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding muObservableCollection}" ... >
```

How can I do it?

Comment: You can use a technique called a "data context proxy".  See here for example (Silverlight, but I think it applies): http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/08/20/creating-a-silverlight-datacontext-proxy-to-simplify-data-binding-in-nested-controls.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.myProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}}" />
```

Should do the trick. However I would like to point out that what you want does not make sense: you bind your TabItem let's say to a Order-instance, the DataGrid to its Orderlines, why do you want a combobox from the Order in the DataGrid? Al the columns will display the same value and if you change one row, the values for all rows change.

I have run into this situation myself a couple of times that I needed access to an higher level (due to refactoring in combination with commands), but it is rather rare.

Comment: Your code is exactly code from my first post (you've only added `DataContext` before `myProperty`. Id does not work. Should it? 
Every row in my `DataGrid` is academic lecturer who have *Name*, *Surname* and *AcademicDegree* which can be chosen from combo box. Academic degrees are fixed and I fetch them from database. That's why I need to change context.

Comment: The diff is important. In your code you bind to a prop that does not  exist on the tabitem, in my version you bind to the datacontext which refs the instance of your object that does have the prop. By the way, your code sets the design time datacontext on the tabitem. Andd

Comment: I did not notice that you bind to the itemssource of the combo. I can see you solve it this way now. However I used to solve the prob a little diff by adding a ref to the shared list to the models binding to the datagrid.